# Converting FILE_NAME_INFORMATION to String in C#

Tags: c#, c++, string, marshalling

I'm using the function NtQueryInformationFile in C# to get information about and open file handle which is returned by the  function. This function gives me a pointer to the following structure:

```
typedef struct _FILE_NAME_INFORMATION {
  ULONG FileNameLength;
  WCHAR FileName[1];
} FILE_NAME_INFORMATION, *PFILE_NAME_INFORMATION;
```

Where:

> FileNameLength Specifies the length, in bytes, of the file name
>   string. FileName Specifies the first character of the file name
>   string. This is followed in memory by the remainder of the string.

How can I convert that to a string in C#?

Comment: do you have any code that youve written so far?

Comment: please see the answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this instead which was more stable in managed code:

```
        var sbPath = new StringBuilder();

        {
            if (FileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                throw (new Exception("Invalid file handle!"));
            }

            GetFinalPathNameByHandle(FileHandle, sbPath, 10000, FILE_NAME_NORMALIZED);
        }
```

Comment: Well, this isn't quite right. You're creating an *empty* `StringBuilder` and then telling the function that it points to a buffer `10000` characters long. That is almost guaranteed to blow up. You can try guessing at the required length when you create your `StringBuilder` (`MAX_PATH` is a reasonable choice), and then handling the condition where the buffer is too small. (Another cardinal sin: you're not checking the result of that function: how will you know if it fails?)

Comment: you are right, that was just the basic version of the solution. I think that I should have posted a more complete one.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "basic". It is completely wrong. What I meant by "isn't quite right" is that you have the idea, but your code is doomed to utter failure. The `StringBuilder` is uninitialized, so the `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` function will be unable to write into it, and then to make matters worse, you're lying to the function and telling it that you've passed it a buffer 10000 characters in length. If you already knew that, but posted this code anyway, then no, you shouldn't do that. Sample code doesn't have to have error checking or whatever, but it should at least *work*.

Comment: I can assure you that it's fully working without any thrown exceptions or unexpected behavior. I've used it as a part of a hook for NtQueryDirectoryFile function to get the name of the current folder, and it worked perfectly. I can even show you that with images/videos if you want.

Comment: Mind-boggling. I guess you are getting amazingly lucky. I took a closer look at the documentation, and it turns out that the default constructor for a `StringBuilder` initializes its capacity to "the implementation-specific default capacity". Your guess is as good as mine about what that is, but clearly it's long enough to hold the string that `GetFinalPathNameByHandle` is trying to return to you. Don't rely on that luck holding out. Path lengths are subject to change at the drop of a hat, and you can't rely on "implementation-specific" behavior.

Comment: Even if you wanted to, you still are lying to the Win32 function about the length of the buffer. You are telling it that it is 10000 characters long, when that probably is *not* "the implementation-specific default capacity" of a `StringBuilder` object. Although buffer overruns are not as big of a problem in managed code, with all the safety net that is provided, they are still a problem when you write unmanaged code. And when you p/invoke into native Win32 functions, you're writing unmanaged code. Which means you're sitting atop a bomb about to blow. I'm not just trying to be nitpicky here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the term you are looking for is "Marshaling" and therefore this Method should do what you want:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms146626(v=vs.110).aspx

```
char[] managedArray = new char[yourDataObject.FileNameLength];
Marshal.Copy(yourDataObject.FileName, managedArray, 0, managedArray.Length);

// and now build your string with your managed array
// using Stringbuilder order something like the below
string myString = new string(managedArray);
```

Comment: I tried this but it kept on crashing:
`IntPtr iprc = NtQueryInformationFile(FileHandle, ref iosb, p_fbi, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(fbi), FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS.FileNamesInformation);

FILE_NAME_INFORMATION fbi = (FILE_NAME_INFORMATION)Marshal.PtrToStructure(p_fbi, typeof(FILE_NAME_INFORMATION));

var bytDest = new byte[fbi.FileNameLength+3];

Marshal.Copy(p_fbi, bytDest, 0, (int)fbi.FileNameLength);

bytDest.ToString()`

Comment: Sorry forgot something: you need to pass the array not the pointer :    `Marshal.Copy(yourDataObject.FileName, managedArray, 0, managedArray.Length);` So your code should be `Marshal.Copy(fbi.Filename, bytDest, 0, (int)fbi.FileNameLength); `

Comment: it kept on giving me access violation errors so I had to use another method instead...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the adequate variant of [Marshal.CopyPtrToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4x4bfws%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) depending on the type of character contained in the structure.

Comment: That's not very informative. How did it not work? Given the definition of the structure, the string is likely *not* zero-terminated, so you need to use the overloads of CopyPtrToString taking both the pointer to the char array and the length of the string.

Comment: I found it easier switching to the command below instead of wasting so much time on string conversion.

Comment: The StringBuilder code you posted? It might marshal as a char array, but you still do need to ensure its capacity is big enough for MAX_PATH chars (262, iIrc, no need to go overboard with 10k) before passing it to the unmanaged code.

Comment: you are right. I've just changed the buffer size to 1000 which I think is a safe bet